# При нажатии на кнопку телефона назад возвращается на предыдущую страницу

Tags: android

Допустим в приложении 3 активити.
С 3й активити переходит на 1ую.
При нажатие на телефонную кнопку назад возвращается с 1-й на третьей (если уже был на этой странице).
Как этого избежать?
Ну то есть из MAIN активити уходит на предыдущую страницу, хочу от этого избавиться.

Comment: Когда переходишь на другое активити после интента вызывай финиш, и после этого на любой активити нажав кнопку назад приложение будет закрываться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы избавится от перехода с вашей главной активности просто перепишите метод `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

этот метод будет вас перебрасывать на ту активити на которой вы находитесь, но с другой стороны вы должны быть уверенны что вашу главную активность вообще можно будет покинуть, ведь пользователь не сможет сидеть на одном экранчике)) Так же вы можете добавить флаги чтобы переход осуществлялся незаметно для пользователя:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

надеюсь этот способ поможет в решении вашей проблемы. Если что-то будет не понятно - не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, поможем чем сможем. Удачи :)